# How to interpolate COUNT in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am creating a number of VMs in Azure with corrosponding NICs and PublicIPs.

I can create unique names for the VMs no problem:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "workernode" {
    count = "${var.nodeCount}"
    name = "workernode-${count.index +1}"
```

and the public IPs:

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "AliasworkerPubIP" {
    count = "${var.nodeCount}"
    name = "workerpubip${count.index +1}"
```

and the NIC:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "workerNIC" {
    count = "${var.nodeCount}"
    name = "workerNIC.${count.index +1}"
```

but I cant work out how to get it to work for then connecting the NIC to the PublicIP just created ...

Have tried various different ways and nothing is clicking ... I know I missing something or not understanding interpolation parsing correctly, but what?!

examples I have tried:

```
public_ip_address_id = "${azurerm_public_ip}.${format("Alias_WorkerIP%d.id", count.index +1)}" 

public_ip_address_id = "${format("Alias_WorkerIP%d.id", count.index +1)}"

public_ip_address_id = "${format("azurerm_public_ip.workerpubip.%s.id", count.index +1)}"
```

any ideas of where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The current recommended way to express this is:

```
public_ip_address_id = "${azurerm_public_ip.workerpubip.*.id[count.index]}"
```

Using this index operator (`[ ... ]`) allows Terraform to understand better the dependency this implies, so that if only one of the public IP instances needs to be replaced it can understand that only the one corresponding `azurerm_network_interface` needs to be updated.

When using the `element` function Terraform only "sees" the `azurerm_public_ip.workerpubip.*.id` expression and assumes, conservatively, that there is a dependency on  *all* of the `azurerm_public_ip` ids.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it:

public_ip_address_id = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.workerpubip.*.id,count.index)}"

Answer (score 0):

try this in azurerm_network_interface module

```
 public_ip_address_id          = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.main-rg__vm-ip.*.id, count.index)}"
```

in azurerm_public_ip module

```
resource azurerm_public_ip main-rg__vm-ip {
  count               = "${var.vm_count}"
  name                = "${var.environment}-vm${count.index+1}-ip"
  location            = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.main-rg.name}"
  sku                 = "Basic"
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"


}
```